# LaTeX, fancyhdr wrong section name in header if using \section*{name}

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, header-footer, fancyhdr

I am  polishing up bibliography in my research paper and I have a problem with fancyhrd showing wrong section name for every but the first page of my bibliography.

This is what I mean:

The first page of bibliography:

[image]

Every other page of bibliography (name of the section before the section called **ZDROJE** is displayed):

[image]

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% Language definition
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[czech]{babel}

% Package definition and folder with images
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Obrazky/} }

% Package difinition
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{tabularx} % Pro vytvoření tabulky, která bude mít full page width, musím zkontrolovat, zda tento package někde v práci něco nerozhodil

% Base header definition
\setlength\headheight{26pt}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=\dimexpr \headheight-\dp\strutbox]{newcevro}}
\rhead{\small{\leftmark}}

% Bibliography definition
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Zdroje.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}

% Footnote package definition
\usepackage{footnote} %Package použitý k tomu, aby byli citace uvnitř float elementů pod čarou
\makesavenoteenv{figure} %Nastavení toho, aby byli citace uvnitř figure pod čarou

% Package definition
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Different language for contents and figures
\renewcommand\contentsname{Obsah}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{Seznam obrázků}
\renewcommand\figurename{Obrázek}

% Special header style definition for sections with long text in header
\fancypagestyle{smallertextinheader}{ 
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=\dimexpr \headheight-\dp\strutbox]{newcevro}}
   \fancyhead[R]{%
   \parbox[b]{\dimexpr \textwidth-3cm-\columnsep}%
   {\small\uppercase\leftmark}}%
   \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

% Special header for contents only
\fancypagestyle{Contents}{
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyhead[LE,LO]{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=\dimexpr \headheight-\dp\strutbox]{newcevro}}
   \fancyhead[RE,RO]{\small{\uppercase{\rightmark}}}
}

% Basic page style definition
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Pretitle definition
\pretitle{
    \begin{center}
    \LARGE
    \includegraphics[width=10cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{newcevro}
}
\posttitle{\end{center}}

% Document body --------------
\begin{document}

\section{Something}
Something
\subsection{Something}
Something
\subsubsection{Something}
Something

% Konec hlavní části práce, následují zdroje
\newpage
\thispagestyle{Contents}
\section*{Zdroje}\markright{ZDROJE}
% Counter definition pro přidání čísla ke zdrojům v obsahu práce, možná číslo odeberu
\newcounter{SecZdroje}
\setcounter{SecZdroje}{\thesection}
\addtocounter{SecZdroje}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\theSecZdroje \hspace{1,7 mm} Zdroje}
% Zde je definováno jak budou vypsány zdroje, přesná specifikace je obsažena v mappingu
\printbibliography[omitnumbers=true,type=misc,heading=subbibliography,title={Online zdroje}]
\printbibliography[omitnumbers=true,type=book,heading=subbibliography,title={Knižní zdroje}]
\printbibliography[omitnumbers=true,type=article,heading=subbibliography,title={Články}]
\printbibliography[omitnumbers=true,type=proceedings,heading=subbibliography,title={Zákony}]    
\end{document}
```

I am using `\section*{}` because I dont want to have number next to my section name in header. How do I force fancyhdr to display **ZDROJE** in the first page where I use `\section*{Zdroje}\markright{ZDROJE}` and in every subsequent page (until there is new section name in header, because next section is defined, or until `\end{document}`)?

I understand this is because I am using `\section*{}` insetead of `\section{}`, but how do I force fancyhdr to work the same way for both definitions?

Is there an environment I can use to wrap the bibliography part of my research paper in to show the same section name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\pagestyle` instead of `\thispagestyle` and wrapping the whole part in braces and then using `\clearpage` helped.